# How to install grails project

Tags: grails, build-process

I've created new grails plugin with this [quick start](http://grails.org/Quick+Start) reference.
How could I install it to local and remote repository to make it available for other plugins to depend on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a grails "plugin", you should be referring to [this information](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins) instead. The one you are referring is for creating a Grails Application.

*Gist:*
Grails app (one you are referring to) creates a deployable component which can be deploed to any container and accessed. On the other hand, grails plugins are extension/modules that are created and maintained separately. packaged as `zip` and are plugged to any Grails Application when required.

If you are creating a grails plugin and want to push it to local/remote repositories, you need to use the [release](http://grails.org/plugin/release) plugin which comes inside a plugin by default.

```
grails maven-install
```

The command is taken from release plugin to push your plugin to local maven repositories, if you have any.